# Python Json implementation bug

Tags: python, json

i have some python that is sopost to use some json and provide some form of low level chat bot this is my python

```
import json
import random

# Load the JSON data from the specified file path
file_path = "E:/Projects/X1OSCB/chatbot_responces.json"
with open(file_path) as file:
    chat_data = json.load(file)

def find_matching_category(user_input, step_data):
    for category, step_data in chat_data.items():
        for words in step_data['words']:
            if words in user_input:
                return category, step_data
    return None, None

def chat(category, step_data):
    print(random.choice(step_data['responses']))
    user_input = input("> ").lower().strip()

    while True:
        if 'answer_from_user' in step_data and any(word in user_input for word in step_data['answer_from_user']['words']):
            print(random.choice(step_data['answer_from_user']['responses']))
            next_category = step_data['answer_from_user'].get('next_category')
            if next_category:
                next_step_data = chat_data.get(next_category)
                if next_step_data:
                    chat(next_category, next_step_data)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            else:
                break

        if 'next_category' in step_data:
            next_category = step_data['next_category']
            next_step_data = chat_data.get(next_category)
            if next_step_data:
                chat(next_category, next_step_data)
                break
            else:
                break
        else:
            break

def restart_chat():
    while True:
        print("Listening for conversation starters...")
        user_input = input("> ").lower().strip()
        category, step_data = find_matching_category(user_input, chat_data)
        if category:
            print(f"Starting conversation in category: {category}")
            chat(category, step_data)
        else:
            print("I'm sorry, I didn't understand that. Please try again.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    restart_chat()
```

and this is my json

```
{
    "greetings": {
        "words": ["hello", "hi"],
        "responses": ["Hi", "Hello"]
    },
    "continuation": {
        "words": ["who are you", "what is your name"], 
        "responses": ["idk", "you tell me"],
        "answer_from_user": {
            "words": ["test"],
            "responses":["confirmed"]

        }
    }
}
```

what it should do is it should ask for user input then search in the json for a dict with that user input inside of its "word" list if this is so it takes a random pick of the responces in the "responces" list in that same dict if the "answer_from_user" list isent there is should restart and ask fro use input again to start another conversation, if the "answer_from_user" dict is in there it will see if the next user input is inside of that dict if so it will respond accordingly with anther random responce from the "responces" list but instead, it asks for the second user input twice like so

```
Listening for conversation starters...
> hello
Starting conversation in category: greetings
Hello
> what is your name
Listening for conversation starters...
> what is your name
Starting conversation in category: continuation
you tell me
>
```

the correct answer woudent make me ask "what is your name" twice eg the perfect responce may look like this

```
Listening for conversation starters...
> hello
Starting conversation in category: greetings
Hello
Listening for conversation starters...
> what is your name
Starting conversation in category: continuation
you tell me
>
```

and if i wanted to continue that conversation the conversation may go like this

```
Listening for conversation starters...
> hello
Starting conversation in category: greetings
Hello
Listening for conversation starters...
> what is your name
Starting conversation in category: continuation
you tell me
> test
confirmed
Listening for conversation starters...
>
```

Comment: Reduce this problem, which _specific_ thing is going wrong? Hardcode your data instead of loading JSON? Still going wrong? Then the problem has nothing to do with JSON. Not going wrong? Then find a _single_ user input that reproduces the problem, and minimize your JSON for that specific case. Then start debugging your drastically simpler use case. Basically: start working on a [mcve], because running through that process almost always lets _you_ figure out the problem without ever having to actually hit "post" on a question you have written up.